# Why does Rails make plural association when it should be singular?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

These are my migrations:

Subject Migration

```
class CreateSubjects < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :subjects do |t|
      t.string "subject_name" , :limit => 25
      #some Values here
    end
  end
  def down 
    drop_table :subjects
  end
end
```

Page Migration

```
class CreatePages < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :pages do |t|
      t.string "page_name" , :limit => 25
      #some Values here
    end
    add_index("pages", "permalink")
    add_reference :pages, :subjects, index: true, foreign_key: true
  end
  def down
    drop_table :pages
  end
end
```

Now the models:

```
class Subject < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :page
end
```

And the Page model:

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

In the rails console, I created a new subject and I should be allowed to run this command:

```
s = Subject.find(1) 
s.page
```

After running this, I get an SQL error, stating that the column `page.subject_id` does not exist. Rails handles plurals and singulars by itself. So I created a page to check the SQL command and this is what shows up:

> Page id: nil, page_name: nil, permalink: nil, visible: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, subjects_id: nil

So it seems that rails miscreated the column; `subjects_id` is the column on the Pages table but the auto generated SQL command to search among the pages the ones that are related to certain Subject is passed as plural.

Help.

Comment: your migration should be: `add_reference :pages, :subject, index: true, foreign_key: true` and not `add_reference :pages, :subjects, index: true, foreign_key: true`

Comment: @bjhaid Thanks! it worked.. my fault!

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be some missing details from your migrations. I'd suggest looking at the [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association) `has_one` Active Record association.

For example, given an active record model:

```
 class Supplier < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :account
 end
```

The associated migration might appear as:

```
 class CreateSuppliers < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :suppliers do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.timestamps null: false
     end

     create_table :accounts do |t|
       t.belongs_to :supplier, index: true
       t.string :account_number
       t.timestamps null: false
     end
   end
 end
```